# How to add rewind function to a mp4 on a presentation in Latex using Mac

Tags: beamer, presentations, movie15

I have been searching and trying to add a video in a presentation. NONE of the solution was useful. I have a macbook pro and I installed the TeXShop of course.
can anybody help me to do it ?

Please make an example if it is possible. simply download a youtube video

```
\documentclass[12pt] {beamer}

\usepackage{animate,media9,movie15}
\begin{document}
% here I have many sections but I directly go to the movie section 
\section{Arrays types}
    \begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
  \includemovie[
    poster,
    autoplay,
    text={\small(sample)}
  ]{6cm}{6cm}{exampleveiode.mp4}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

This is for sure working but the problem is that I don't have any option to stop, rewind the video. can anybody help please ?

Comment: Do you want the video to automatically rewind after reaching the end or at any time in between start and end? Are you willing to use the keyboard for controlling the playback, or do you insist on inserting clickable buttons for this? All this is possible with the `media9` package.

Comment: @AlexG media9 did not work for me, can you please provide me with an example ? so that I will try it out

Comment: Ok, I will prepare one, but AdobeReader is needed and the MP4 must be encoded with the h264 codec.

Answer (score 1):

With `media9`, there are several ways to interact with the video. The easiest perhaps, using the keyboard, is documented in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf#page=20&view=FitH,0):

[image]

Alternatively, control buttons can be inserted and also the video be configured to rewind after reaching the end:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Video}

  For keyboard control, see the manual, page 20.

  \includemedia[
%    width=6cm,
%    height=6cm,
    label=my_video,
    activate=pageopen,
    addresource=cube.mp4,
    flashvars={
      source=cube.mp4     % same path as in addresource!
     &autoRewind=true     % rewind after end
%     &loop=true           % loop video (doesn't make sense with autoRewind)
    }
  ]{\includegraphics{cubeposter}}{VPlayer.swf}

  \mediabutton[mediacommand=my_video:playPause]{\fbox{\strut Play/Pause}}
  \mediabutton[
    mediacommand=my_video:pause,
    mediacommand=my_video:rewind
  ]{\fbox{\strut Stop}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```